# Filters in Angular

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

i just started working with angular and i need to filter what i show based on a item selected from a dropdown list.

```
 <div title="{{agreement.number}} - {{agreement.provider}}" ng-show="agreement.provider.toLowerCase().indexOf(searchParam.toLowerCase()) != -1 || agreement.sa_id.toLowerCase().indexOf(searchParam.toLowerCase()) != -1" ng-repeat="agreement in tableList | orderBy : 'number' track by $index | filter: provider:selectedProduct ">
  <a href="#" style="display:block;">
    <div class="itemContainerList" ng-class="{'gridview': !ListView , 'listViewAnimate': ListView}">
      <div>
        <div class="alignItemContainerList">
          <div>
            <img class="list_normal" src="img_list_logo_blank_hsbcSA.svg" />
            <img class="list_hover" src="img_list_logo_geralSA.svg" />
          </div>
          <div class="alignItemContainerText">
            {{agreement.number}} - {{agreement.provider}}
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </a>
</div>
```

My javascript code is the following:

```
<!-- language: javascript -->
$scope.selectItem = function(car) {
    $scope.selectedBusiness = car;
    $scope.showList = false;
    $scope.overlay = false;
};
```

Comment: show your drop down code

Comment: ng-repeat="agreement in tableList | orderBy : 'number' track by $index | filter: selectedItem

Comment: <select ng-model="selectedItem"></select>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have an element which you are trying to use as a filter, then it should be as below,

```
<input type="text" ng-model="search.fullname"/>
```

And then you will have to add a filter at the end as specified below

```
<div ng-repeat="agreement in tableList | orderBy : 'number' track by $index | filter: search">
```

Refer this link for more info https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/filter